# Replacing a non-copyable, non-movable object

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, c++14, placement-new

Consider the following code:

```
// A non-copyable, non-movable aggregate
struct Strange
{
    const int & i;
    char & c;
};

class Container
{
    private:
        int  my_i;
        char my_c;
        Strange thing;

    public:
        // Valid, because both `my_i´ and `my_c´ are non-const
        // objects to which both references can be bound.
        explicit
            Container
            ( )
            noexcept
            : thing{ my_i , my_c }
            { }

        // How could this be implemented?
        auto &
            operator=
            ( const Container & that )
            noexcept
            {
                this->my_i = that->my_i;
                this->my_c = that->my_c;

                // What to do with `thing´?

                return *this;
            }
};
```

---

### Possible solutions

1. **Dynamically allocate the `Strange` object**

   ```
   class Container
   {
       private:
           int  my_i;
           char my_c;
           Strange * thing;

       public:
           // Note that it isn't exception safe.
           explicit
               Container
               ( )
               : thing(new Strange{ my_i , my_c })
               { }

           auto &
               operator=
               ( const Container & that )
               noexcept
               {
                   this->my_i = that->my_i;
                   this->my_c = that->my_c;

                   delete this->thing;
                   this->thing = new Strange { this->my_i , this->my_c };

                   return *this;
               }
   };
   ```

   Concerns:

   - Not efficient.
   - Not safe: allocation may fail and throw.
   - Dangerous: great care has to be taken not to leak memory.

     Using a smart pointer (i.e. `std::unique_ptr`) would solve only the last point, aside from making the code more readable.
2. **Use placement new**

   ```
   class Container
   {
       private:
           int  my_i;
           char my_c;
           Strange thing;

       public:
           explicit
               Container
               ( )
               noexcept
               : thing{ my_i , my_c }
               { }

           auto &
               operator=
               ( const Container & that )
               noexcept
               {
                   this->my_i = that.my_i;
                   this->my_c = that.my_c;

                   // Placement new is exception safe, and so is
                   // construction of `Strange´.
                   this->thing.~Strange();
                   new(&this->thing) Strange { this->my_i , this->my_c };

                   return *this;
               }
   };
   ```

   Concerns:

   - Will `Strange`'s destructor free the memory taken by `thing`?

     I think that, just as constructors, destructors are not responsible for memory management. Moreover, my code seems to work fine. However, I would like clarification on this.
   - What about memory alignment?

     My guess is that, since it replaces an existing object of the same type, memory would already be aligned. Is this correct?
   - Would `Container`'s destructor take care of destructing `thing`?

### Questions

Aside from corroborating and/or refuting the concerns I explained above, I would like to know if there are other alternatives. If so, please, give an example implementation.

---

This question arose when working on a class that ought to offer an interface similar to that of `std::unordered_map`. Instead of reimplementing it, my class encapsulates such container, and just acts as a proxy for most methods: its iterators envelop those provided by the map, and its pair is an aggregate structure with appropiately named members (*which are references to the actual data*), represented in the examples provided as `Strange`. Since iterators are required to return references and pointers to the actual data, my custom iterators contain a pair. The problem was modifying it (when incrementing or assigning the iterator). I acknowledge that this probably isn't a good idea, and that those references *will* impact performance, but am anyway interested in the matter.

#### Edit

I have just realized that, instead of returning references and pointers to a member custom pair pointing to the actual data (that of the encapsulated map) from my custom iterator, I could return in-place constructed custom pairs (i.e. `Strange` objects). Often, we do not see that we are in a cave, and instead of exiting it, continue forward :). Excuse me for the noise, I'll mark the question as "Closed".

Comment: Since `thing` contains self-references, in the code you posted you don't need to do *anything* to it in your copy assignment operator.

Comment: @T.C. You are right, my example is broken. Reading the last paragraph could help understanding my problem, while I try to provide a better example.

Comment: AFAIK, placement new requires you to call destructor manually, if needed. Otherwise it does not clean. Also, could you declare copy and move constructors deleted?

Comment: @sukhmel Thanks, that's what I suspected :). The assignment operator, and in general modifying `Container`, is necessary because, in reality, it's a custom iterator that wraps an `std::unordered_map`'s. As I also wanted to provide my own pairs with named members, the iterator had to encapsulate them as well. But the references must be changed when the iterator is incremented.

Comment: @Kalrish: If you do want to change what they refer to, you're probably better off using pointers, rather than trying to force references to behave unlike references.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I wanted to maintain consistency (my custom container's interface should be the same, regardless of how it is implemented): if I had implemented the map myself, my custom pairs should be the actual data, and pointers would no longer fit. But I have just realized that this question is absurd, and edited it accordingly. Thank you all! :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a (bad) solution to other problem. The last problem would vanish with the correct solution to the root one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(If we're talking about moving objects and using the `auto` keyword, you should add the `c++11` tag to your question).*

I'm not sure I really understand your question; the example you gave doesn't seem well thought to me; it would be much better to use pointers in `Strange`. 
For example, this compiles and works absolutely fine, and is functionally equivalent to what you want to do I think.

```
struct Strange
{
    Strange()
        : i(nullptr), c(nullptr) {}
    Strange( const int *_i, const char *_c )
        : i(_i), c(_c) {}

    const int *i;
    const char *c;
};

class Container
{
    int  my_i;
    char my_c;
    Strange thing;

    public:

        Container()
            : thing(&my_i,&my_c)
            { }

        Container( int i, char c )
            : my_i(i), my_c(c), thing(&my_i,&my_c)
            { }

        Container( int i, char c, const Strange& s )
            : my_i(i), my_c(c), thing(s) // use default copy-constructor
            { }

        Container &
            operator=
            ( const Container & that )
            {
                my_i  = that.my_i;
                my_c  = that.my_c;
                thing = that.thing;

                return *this;
            }
};

int main()
{
    Container a(12,24);
    Container b(25,42);
    b = a;
}
```

Note that referencing memory within objects is generally dangerous. 
For example, using `memcpy` on this would be a catastrophy.
(Compiled with clang and g++)

Comment: You missed my point that `Strange` **must** contain references -as I explained in a comment above, to maintain consistency-, but it was my fault for not providing an appropiate example. As a completely unrelated note, you should use `NULL` or (preferably) `nullptr` instead of `0`. Thanks for answer :).

Comment: I wasn't sure about nullptr because there was no c++11 tag. My question to you then is, why not use pointers?

Comment: I have edited the question as you suggested. As for your question, I'm working on a custom class with similar functionality to that of `std::unordered_map`. The problem comes with iterators and pairs. I want my pairs to have named members, i.e., not `first` and `second`. To achieve that, my custom pairs merely contain references - they thus are like real pairs. But, as iterators have to return references and pointers (operator* and operator->), those custom pairs must be stored somewhere (in each iterator). And when it is incremented, or copied...

Comment: So all this trouble just to name the members of a `std::pair` differently? Do you think it is worth it? You could just define a role within the context in which you are processing the iterators that provides another "namespace" (literally, not the c++ ones..). I think it would be simpler and cleaner. :)

Comment: As it isn't anything professional, it's as worth as pleasant. So... More or less. Anyway, there should be way to name those differently. They aren't very descriptive.